# Collect the common term in mathematica

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization

I have a complicated **expression of x1, x2, x3,...,x10**. **They includes 4 operation (+,-,*,/) and Square root**

and I would like to collect the common term for each variables.

For example I have

**F = x1 + 2*x2 + 5x3 -Sqrt(x4 + x5) + x7 +...something long and complicated**

I want to change into below form:

**F = A*x1 + B*x2 + C*x3 + D*x4 +...+(something)*xn**

Please help if is there any way to do this in mathematica?

Comment: Hong, you will be better off asking this question at mathematica.stackexchange.com which span off from SO recently.

Comment: Check for `Collect[]` at the help

Comment: There is no way to do this at all.. the quantity in the sqrt has to stay there.  Can you provide a complete example of input and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Try using CoefficientList and then Total and Table. Something like this:

`cef = CoefficientList[a + b x + c x + Sin[c] x^2 + x^2 + x^3, x];
Total[Table[cef[[i]] x^i, {i, 1, 4}]]`

Try also Collect[] which should work even with sqrt(x). However if you have some thing like Sqrt(x4 + x5) I don't really think you can take it apart, can you?